# How do I set up a web.py apache2 server on an amazon linux ubuntu 13.04 server?

Tags: apache, web.py

Web.py is free and lightweight. Amazon also provides you with a free web service for a year. How do I set up apache2 onto my server?

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT: Formatting this is impossible. I'll try to do it later. I have such a beautifully written .txt file with fantastic formatting.

I apologize if this isn't thorough. I worked through how to set it up for my very specific setup. However, some of the annoying tricks are solved and may help you on your journey to set it up!!!

I won't walk you through signing up for amazon. There are a million tutorials out there.

Make sure you have an amazon ec2 instance up and running for ubuntu 13.04. Once you're logged in and have your instance launched, get the following going

*I've omitted some numbers as they are specific to our application and don't help.

1. Give yourself root access
   sudo su (if you do this you dont need to sudo anything)
2. Get Apache 2
   apt-get install apache2 apache2.2-common apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils libexpat1 ssl-cert
3. Get Pip
   apt-get install python-pip
4. Get web.py
   pip install web.py
5. Get MySQL
   apt-get install python-mysql.connector python-mysqldb mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-server
       set password to: whatever password you want
6. Get mod_wsgi
    apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi

   6.1 Check to see its working
   service apache2 restart
   put ip address in web browser to see if it works
7. enable mod_rewrite
   a2enmod rewrite
8. SFTP (filezilla)
   8.1 Giving permissions to allow filezilla in
    cd /var/www
    mkdir legal #this is our main directory. Name it whatever you want
    chown -R ubuntu /var/www/
    chmod -R 755 /var/www/
   8.2 Connecting in Filezilla
    Open Site manager
     host: some ip like 54.213.173.233
           Port: 22
           Protocol: SFTP
           Login Type: Normal
           User: Ubuntu
           Pass: empty
       Edit -> Setting -> SFTP: add your key
   8.3 Add all of your code Using Filezilla

9 Modifying your code:
    go to your main.py
    9.1 Wsgifunc()
    #add these somewhere in your main file
    app = web.application(urls, globals(),autoreload=False)
    application = app.wsgifunc()
    web.config.debug = True #  Change to False
    db = web.database(dbn='mysql', host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='user goes here', pw='pas goes here', db='')

9.2 Ensure python can find all of your files

AT THE TOP OF YOUR FILE 
    import os
    import sys
    root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**)+"/")
    sys.path.insert(0, root)
    modules = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**)+"/server/")
    sys.path.insert(1, modules)
    os.chdir(root)
    os.environ["SCRIPT_NAME"] =''
    os.environ["REAL_SCRIPT_NAME"] = ''

1. Configuration of apache
   cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

   10.1 Changing the default file
   vim default
   change everything to:
       *our main folder is called /legal. In it we have our icons and favicons and such in /static. Change these accordingly

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
           DocumentRoot /var/www/legal/
           DirectoryIndex main.py
           WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/legal/
           Alias /static /var/www/legal/static/
           
                   Options FollowSymLinks
                   AllowOverride None
           
           
                   Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                   #changed from non to FileInfo
                   AllowOverride FileInfo Options
                   Order allow,deny
                   allow from all
           
           #ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
           #
           #        AllowOverride None
           #        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
           #        Order allow,deny
           #        Allow from all
           #
           ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
           # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
           # alert, emerg.
           LogLevel info
           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   10.2 Test to see if there are errors
       apachectl configtest

   10.3 Monitor For errors when messing with config files (optional)
       tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
       and

11 Creating a .htaccess file
    cd /var/www/legal #this is where our main file is located
    vim .htaccess
    Then add:
        
            SetHandler wsgi-script
            Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
        
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^favicon.ico$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/.*)+main.py/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/.*)+.(css|png|js|jpg|ttf|otf|gif|ico)$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.py/$1 [PT]

```
#for reals, it never copies correctly... just a heads up
```

12 Setting up the database
    cd /var/www/legal/server/subapplications
    mysql -u root -p'whatever password you want'

```
12.1 create the database in sql
    create database intravires;
    ###do whatever you need to do here
    quit
```

13 Restart
     service apache2 restart
    13.1 If broken,Check the logs:
        tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

14 Profit!